# Get the type of std::bind at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, bind

How can I get the type of a `std::bind` expression to store it in a class member? For example, I have this:

```
template<class F, class ...Args>
void foo(F&& funct, Args&&... args) {
  typedef decltype(std::bind(funct, std::forward<Args>(args)...)) T;
  T bar = std::bind(funct, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

But I want to convert it into:

```
template<class F, class ...Args>
class Foo {
  void foo(F&& funct, Args&&... args) {
    bar = std::bind(funct, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  T bar;  // what is the type of bar?
}
```

Comment: You might use `std::function<void()>` ?

Comment: This is easier in C++14 than C++11.  Also, this seems like a dangerous or bad idea for more than one reason (one of which is that bind is crazy magic in the corner cases)

Answer (score 6):

[`std::declval()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) is your friend.

The type is

```
decltype(std::bind(std::declval<F&>(), std::declval<Args>()...))
```

Comment: "How can I shoot myself in the foot" "well, first you have to remove the safety...".  +1, it does answer the question!

Answer (score 1):

`std::function` seems simpler. But you could use:

```
template<class F, class ...Args>
class Foo {
    using T = decltype(std::bind(std::declval<F>(), std::declval<Args>()...));

  Foo(F&& funct, Args&&... args) : bar(std::bind(funct, std::forward<Args>(args)...))
  {}
  T bar;
};
```

Note that `std::bind` return type has not to be default constructible.